# Container builder compilation with multiple extensions

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm currently trying to test one of my symfony2 extension. For that, I have instanciated a container builder & then register my extension on it.

The problem is my extension needs other extensions to be compiled (some services from other extensions are injected in my tested extension services). So, I have register these other extensions before mine in order to be able to compile the container.

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();

$container->registerExtension(new AcmeOtherExtension());
$container->registerExtension(new AcmeMainExtension());

// Loads configuration

$container->compile();
```

At this moment, the container refuses to compile, IMO due to some missing compilation passes. So, I have added this lines:

```
$container->getCompilerPassConfig()->setOptimizationPasses(array(new ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass()));
$container->getCompilerPassConfig()->setRemovingPasses(array());
```

With these lines, the container can be compiled without any errors but when I request one service which have injected services which comes from the other extension, the container throws an exception which notifies me the services defines in the other extension does not exist.

Can someone give me tips about container passes & compilation?

Comment: A simpler way would be to create a Kernel, add your bundles to it, and boot the kernel. For example, look at https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/tree/master/Tests/Functional